# How to make UIPinchGestureRecognizer work for VoiceOver?

Tags: ios, voiceover

I couldn't figure out how to trigger `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` when `VoiceOver` is on. Is it possible to make it work? How?

Comment: Would you mind explaining the specific use case because some solutions may be possible and appropriate according to the environment, please? 

Comment: To switch between 2 modes of displaying media content: fit and fill.

Comment: I'm not sure that adding a new gesture is the best way to reach your goal using VoiceOver. Personally, I would use the rotor instead (https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-rotor) or add custom actions somewhere in your interface (https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-actions) off the top of my head.

Comment: Moreover, I don't think it's even possible to make a custom UIPinchGestureRecognizer work for VoiceOver. The only way I see is to use a specific area where VoiceOver is off  and where your dedicated gesture is on using the UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction trait for instance but, for your use case, I would follow my previous comment. 

Comment: I think I'll use rotor, thanks!